# How to create two mapping methods with different anotations

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

I created this mapping methods:

```
  public abstract User map(UserDTO user);

  @Mapping(source = "user.roles", target = "rolesIds")
  public abstract UserDTO mapWithRoles(User user, boolean roles);
```

As you can see both methods have the same signatures which causes errors when it comes to implicit mappings in other entities. I solved it for now by adding the "roles" parameter to second method which is there only to make a diffeferent method signature.

The thing is I have two methods on repository to get users, one with permissions and one without them and I need to map loaded permissions to permissionIds on DTO.

How do I make two mapping methods that differ in anotations but have the same signature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on which method should be your default you should annotated one of them with `@Named` or a custom `@Qualifier`. If that is the case the annotated method will not be considered, it will only be considered if it is explicitly used in `@Mapper#qualifiedBy` or `@Mapper#qualifiedByName`.

For more information have a look [here](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#selection-based-on-qualifiers) in the reference documentation